# Поиск простых чисел с многопоточностью

Tags: многопоточность, простые-числа

пытаюсь написать максимально быструю программу для поиска простых чисел. Пока лучший результат (он представлен в коде) находит все простые чиса до миллиона за 0,971 секунду на моем компьютере. Алгоритмически более никак результат не могу улучшить (возможно, вы знаете как, я с радостью послушаю), пришло в голову прикрутить многопоток. В питоне это можно было сделать относительно просто с помощью дополнительной библиотеки Numba. А как с этим состоят дела в C++? Просто сколько искал, не смог найти внятного объяснения. И имеет ли вообще смысл улучшать дальше или даже идеально работающий многопоток не даст никакого прироста (тогда почему?)?

P.S. Функцию вызываю три раза просто для большей точности, в качестве значений беру среднее по 3м измерениям

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

void IsPrime() {

float start_time = clock(); //Засекаем время начала

int n = 10000000; //Задаем число, до которого будем перебирать.
int count = 0; //Переменная count - количество простых чисел, которорое мы получим после работы алгоритма.

for (int i = 3; i < n + 1; i+=2) { //Алгоритм перебора
    bool check = true;
    for (int j = 3; j < (int)sqrt(i)+1; j+=2) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            check = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (check) {
        count++;
    }
    else {
        check = true;
    }
}

float end_time = clock(); //Засекаем время  конца
float final_time = (end_time - start_time) / 1000.0; //Считаем итоговое время
cout << "Всего простых чисел: " << count+1 << '\n' << "Времени потрачено: " << final_time << " секунд" << endl;
}

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");

IsPrime(); //Первый замер
IsPrime(); //Второй замер
IsPrime(); //Третий замер

}
```

Comment: у меня ваш код 5,2 сек занимает, вы на каком железе гоняете то? :)

Comment: Для начала можно написать j * j <= i вместо j < (int)sqrt(i)+1 , что работает намного быстрее. Напримем у меня после замены на 3 секунды быстрее отрабатывает

Comment: @vlad9i2, вы в дебаггере что ли запускаете? я просто `const int limit = (int)sqrt(i) + 1; for (int j = 3; j < limit; j += 2) ` сделал - эффекта 0 - те же 5.2 сек

Comment: @Zhihar на i7 8700, не исключаю что у других будет медленее. Но все таки 5,2 у вас многовато как-то

Comment: @vlad9i2 вы правы, теперь стало вообще 0, 072 секунды

Comment: Делить нужно не на все нечетные подряд, а на уже найденные простые.

Comment: Кстати, ветка else { check = true; } не нужна, потому что после неё сразу же будет bool check = true;

Comment: @Эникейщик, я это попробовал реализовать - у меня заметно дольше стало работать :(, что на векторе, что на массиве. Если `Andrew` решит у себя проверить, то размер массива можно выбрать `2 * log(N)` по теореме о кол-ве простых чисел

Comment: @Эникейщик согласен, однако это дает прирост в скорости на уровне погрешности. Впрочем, все равно исправлю (я про if else)

Comment: @Andrew ну да, там пожалуй накладные расходы на организацию этих простых слишком большие будут.

Comment: я там ответ кинул - вы анализируете каждое второе число, но можно анализировать числа по формуле `6k-1` и `6k+1` - все простые числа выше 3 удовлетворяют этому свойству, так что вместо каждого второго в среднем будете проверять каждое третье число - какая никакая, а оптимизация

Comment: @Zhihar да, я увидел, спасибо. Сейчас попробую сделать

Comment: я чуть код скорректировал - в общем смысл в том, что по этой формуле идем как по обычным числам, так и по числам второго, внутреннего цикла, но надо дополнительно проверить в самом начале, что `N > 3`, а во внутренних циклах кратность `3` (привел в коде)

Comment: @Zhihar использовал ваш код. Однако количество чисел отличается. Проверял и при миллионе (там расхождение около 200 чисел)  и при сотне. В вашем коде простых чисел в сотне получается 26, а их там 25. Свою единицу на строчке вывода я убрал, не переживайте

Comment: @Zhihar там даже круче ситуация... Я вывел на экран все числа и... их оказалось наоборот меньше 25. Там пропущены многие числа, всего получилось 12 простых чисел (они верны, однако их мало). Т.е. еще и счетчик где то сломался

Comment: @Andrey, я показал принцип, посмотрел код, исправил ошибку и перезалил - там была проблема в обработке делителей на 5 (надо было `sqrt(i) + 6` сделать, а не `sqrt(i) + 1` раз с шагом в 6 идем) из-за этого цифры и отличались, сейчас не отличаются вообще - так что можете пробовать

Comment: кстати избавление от проверки (в комментарии написал) `if (check)` дало прирост ~ 1%

Comment: @Zhihar да, теперь все одинаково работает. Дает прирост около 15 процентов получается относительно моего. Спасибо!

Comment: кстати я думаю ваша скорость объясняется еще и большим кешем чем у меня - скорее всего удается полностью запихнуть в кеш код

Comment: @Zhihar В итоге получилось добиться скорости в 0,061 секунды) до миллиона

Comment: а... так вы на миллионе проверяете просто в коде изначально у вас 10 миллионов на которых я проверял :)

Comment: @Zhihar а, да, в коде который я прислал оказалось 10 миллионов, хотя в основном я проверял до миллиона. На 10 миллионах результат 1.394 секунды

Comment: у меня 35 - так что это уже терпимо :) а то я подумал что что-то с компьютером случилось уже :)

Comment: @Andrew, я в своем ответе чуть обновил код, удалил лишние проверки и раздвоил цикл, стало чуть чуть чуть побыстрее работать

Comment: Парни, я прошу извинения, но у меня наивный ворос: Вы создали опттимальный однопоточный алгоритм. А многопоочность будете прикручивать?

Comment: @S.H. просто делим n на диапазоны - `for(i = 5 + thread_id * 6; i < n + 1; i += threads_count * 6) {...} for(i = 7 + thread_id * 6; i < n + 1; i += threads_count * 6) {...}` - распределение чисел в этом случае будет равномерным на все потоки

Answer (score 4):

Битовое [решето Эратосфена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0) для нечётных чисел. Это последовательный алгоритм.

Когда построены простые до миллиарда, можно применить [сегментированное решето Эратосфена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0#%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE): числа от 10^9 до 10^18 разбить на сегменты по миллиарду. В каждом сегменте выполнять просеивание. Это уже параллельный алгоритм. Когда очередное ядро просеяло очередной сегмент его печатают и выбрасывают.

Битовая маска одного сегмента 64MB, скажем, восемь сегментов параллельно - полгига. 203 мегабайта нужно для простых до миллиарда. На всё про всё не больше гига и вы будете просеивать простые со скоростью миллиард чисел в секунду (загибаю, такая производительность будет только для первых сегментов, дальше будет медленнее). Процесс закончится через миллиард секунд (32 года) - вы дойдёте до 10^18.

Процесс можно распределить между любым количеством компьютеров. Обработка отдельных сегментов не зависит друг от друга.

Но если вы действительно решите идти этим путём, то есть ещё более эффективные алгоритмы.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void print_primes(const unsigned long long n) {
    const unsigned long long n2 = n / 2;
    std::vector<bool> sieve(n2, true);
    if (2 < n) {
        std::cout << 2 << '\n';
        unsigned long long k;
        for (k = 1; ; ++k) {
            if (sieve[k]) {
                const unsigned long long i = 2 * k + 1;
                const unsigned long long i2 = i * i;
                if (i2 >= n) {
                    break;
                }
                std::cout << i << '\n';
                for (unsigned long long j = i2 / 2; j < n2; j += i) {
                    sieve[j] = false;
                }
            }
        }
        for (; k < n2; ++k) {
            if (sieve[k]) {
                std::cout << 2 * k + 1 << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    unsigned long long n;
    if (std::cin >> n) {
        print_primes(n);
    }
}
```

Девять секунд до миллиарда:

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 sieve-of-eratosthenes.cpp
>
> $ time echo 10000000 | ./a.out | wc -l
> 664579
>
> real  0m0.073s
> user  0m0.068s
> sys   0m0.012s
>
> $ time echo 100000000 | ./a.out | wc -l
> 5761455
>
> real  0m0.707s
> user  0m0.756s
> sys   0m0.028s
>
> $ time echo 1000000000 | ./a.out | wc -l
> 50847534
>
> real  0m8.295s
> user  0m8.808s
> sys   0m0.304s
> ```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте воспользоватьcя тем свойством простых чисел, что любое простое число больше 3 представимо в виде `6k - 1` или `6k + 1`

```
if (n > 10)
    count = 4;

for (int i = 5; i < n + 1; i += 6) {

    const int limit = (int)sqrt(i) + 6;

    count++;

    for (int j = 6; j < limit; j += 6) {
        if ((i % (j - 1) == 0) || (i % (j + 1) == 0)) {
            count--;
            break;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 7; i < n + 1; i += 6) {

    const int limit = (int)sqrt(i) + 6;

    count++;

    for (int j = 6; j < limit; j += 6) {
        if ((i % (j - 1) == 0) || (i % (j + 1) == 0)) {
            count--;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Замечание очень верное! Можно пойти дпальше, прогоняя числа через небольшое решето Эратосфена, а потом уже запуская "настоящую" проверку на простоту!

Comment: Stanislav Volodarskiy выше предложил битовое решето - очень хорошая скорость